# .NET MVC - 2 foreach loops

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach

My code goes like this;
First Loop

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.IsValid && item.IsRecommended)
        {
```

and the second one

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.IsValid && !item.IsRecommended)
        {
```

I am using "@using PagedList; @using PagedList.Mvc;"

i want my page to display recommended products first and than the rest of the products. There is 15 products/page and 150 products in total.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

In Your Model Create Two Classes For RecommendedProduct.cs and RestOfProducts.cs
Create new Model Class

```
 public class Products 
 {
     public List<RecommendedProduct> RecommenedProd { get; set; }
     public List<RestOfProducts> RestProd { get; set; }
 }
```

In Controller

```
 public ActionResult Create()
 {
    Products Obj = new Products();
    Obj.RecommenedProd  = Your recommend product ;//Your Recommended Product List
    Obj.RestProd  = Your recommend product ;//Your rest of product List 
    return View(Obj);
 }
```

View

```
@model Products 

@foreach (var item in Model.RecommenedProd )
{
    // Do Something 
}

@foreach (var item in Model.RestProd )
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: thank you for your effort, let me try it and get back to you.

Comment: I used View.Bag's and well, it does not work as i hoped for maybe i made a mistake but in paged view (PagedList.Mvc) it takes only the first 15 product for the first page now i am gonna try your way...